# Path to career in bioinformatics?

Tags: genomics

I've been completing various courses on bioinformatics through edX and Coursera, and I've made a strong footing in the material.

I'm not sure what to pursue next in bioinformatics that would bring me closer to research in the field or employment.

I don't have bioinformatics at my university and thus am unsure of how to progress.

I have a background in mathematics, chemistry, physics and computer science. So, what would you recommend I do next?

Comment: Welcome to the site Rock910. The site is about questions while doing bioinformatics not about the career. I think it would be better suited for [meta]. However I would say that what you need now is to find a job or start doing some analysis in bioinformatics (Although some more background in biology wouldn't hurt). But that depends on what do you like and what do you want to do

Comment: Thanks @Llopis, I'll ask it in the meta, I appreciate your comment and advice.

Comment: @Rock910 try also https://www.reddit.com/r/bioinformatics/ which as more information about that subject - plenty of old threads with similar questions to yours.

Comment: Do you ask on bioinfo career or good bioinfo materials? One belongs to academia.SE and the second here.

Answer (score 3):

The [Bioinformatics Stronghold at Rosalind](http://rosalind.info) is an excellent resource for building your understanding of many concepts and algorithms you'll see frequently in bioinformatics and genomics.

I'd also say that, if you can make it work, an internship where you can "get your hands dirty" with real problems is a very valuable experience. This option may not be available to everyone due to a variety of factors, but when it is an option it provides a tremendous opportunity to build experience with little risk to the intern or the employer.